# Как построить график по разным структурам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Загружаю данные [датасета iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html).

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=False)
X = data.data
y = data.target
names = data.target_names
```

X, y, names - numpy array, для графика нужны DataFrame

```
dfy = pd.DataFrame(y)
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
dfy = dfy.rename(columns={0: 'y'})
df_ = pd.concat([df,dfy], axis = 1)

sns.pairplot(df_, hue = 'y')
```

Можно было б еще один столбец добавить с names и их выводить по условию.
Находила готовый датасет с DataFrame, [где все уже есть](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). 
Но у меня другая задача. Дан этот датасет с типом данных Bunch.
Как упростить весь код, чтобы целевые наименования names появились
в графике при использовании трех разных X, y, names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(
         data.data, 
         columns=data.feature_names)
        .assign(target=data.target_names[data.target]))
sns.pairplot(df, hue="target")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

DataFrame:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)     target
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2     setosa
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2     setosa
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2     setosa
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2     setosa
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2     setosa
5                  5.4               3.9                1.7               0.4     setosa
6                  4.6               3.4                1.4               0.3     setosa
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...        ...
143                6.8               3.2                5.9               2.3  virginica
144                6.7               3.3                5.7               2.5  virginica
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3  virginica
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9  virginica
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0  virginica
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3  virginica
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8  virginica

[150 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Сильно и стильно выглядит. Спасибо.